# Remove MoreClipboard from Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, clipboard

To be specific, i've installed More Clipboard 1.6 in mu Eclipse Juno. Now i cant't find myself using it comfortably, so 've decided to remove it.

So i uninstalled it from eclipse (help, about, etc), but when i click ctrl+c Eclipse continues to show me that disturbing dialog that blocks my input, that yellow diwlog bottom right.

Can someone help me? thanks.

Answer (score 6):

1. Close Eclipse.
2. Search and remove all "moreclipboard" and "MoreClipboard" lines in:

   Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi
3. Start Eclipse.

If it is not working close Eclipse and search and remove all "moreclipboard" lines in your ~/.eclipse folder.